# Autowired VelocityEngine is not working

Tags: spring-boot, velocity, autowired

I have below code to read templates from database using velocityEngine

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() throws VelocityException, IOException {
  VelocityEngineFactory factory = new VelocityEngineFactory();
  DataSourceResourceLoader ds = new DataSourceResourceLoader();
  ds.setDataSource(dataSource);
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("resource.loader", "ds");
  props.put("ds.resource.loader.instance", ds);
  props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.table", "tb_velocity_template");
  props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.keycolumn", "id_template");
  props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.templatecolumn", "template_definition");
  props.put("ds.resource.loader.resource.timestampcolumn", "template_timestamp");
  factory.setVelocityProperties(props);
  return factory.createVelocityEngine();
}
```

I have another EmailService as below :-

@service
 public class emailService{

@Autowired
  private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

public void sendEmail(){
subject =
          VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
              "WelcomeEmail", "Utf-8", context);
}
}

VelocityEngine is not able find resource WelcomeEmail, eventhough it is present in tb_velocity_template table.

I am not sure, why velocityengine which I have configured in ApplicationConfiguration file is not getting autowired in mailservice.

Comment: How do you have the VelocityEngine object configured in your application context file?

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})

After adding this to my ApplicationConfiguration file, velocity engine is now able to read templates from database. Cheers :)